# How to convert shapefile to mapinfo file preserving special characters?

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, convert, ogr2ogr, encoding

I have to convert a bunch of shapefiles to mapinfo files on a machine without a MapInfo license, so I am using ogr2ogr to perform this task.

The problem is that when opening the mapinfo files in MapInfo Professional, the table's Portuguese characters like Ã are not there any longer. E.g.:

- SÃO PAOLO = SÃfO PAULO
- BRASÍLIA = BRASÃLIA
- GOIÂNIA = GOIÃ,NIA

When opening the same input shapefile through MapInfo Professional (File|Open|Choosing Windows US & Western Europe (ANSI)), I do get the correct result.

I tried lots of different combinations in ogr2ogr using:

- SHAPE_ENCODING
- -lco ENCODING
- intermediate formats (conversion in 2 go's)
- etc.

I cannot seem to get it right.
Does anyone have **THE** solution? :-)

Comment: (Late Reply!) Can you use QGIS? Import the Mapinfo file in question, set the correct encoding in **Layer Properties** > **General** (Tab), then **Save As** anything QGIS supports (via GDAL/OGR).